# Timer callback function do not working when action server be called?

Tags: c++, moveit, action, ros-kinetic, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

##Timer callback function do not working when action server be called?##
Hello, I find a interested problem just now. It was `action server callback function` may cause `timer callback function` do not work.

The reason why I put action-server & timer in same class is that it will be convenient to communicate between `Arduino`&`Moveit`. So timer callback function is used for reading & writing data, and action server callback function is used for getting way points. Here is a part of my code.

```
#ifndef LEAFROBOT_H
#define LEAFROBOT_H
#include "leaf_driver/ManipulatorProtocol.h"

class LeafRobot : public hardware_interface::RobotHW
{
public:
    LeafRobot(),
        as_(nh_, "leaf_controller/follow_joint_trajectory", 
           boost::bind(&LeafRobot::executeCB, this, _1), 
           false)
    {
       .......
       clock = 0.02;    //0.02s
       timer = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(clock), &LeafRobot::timerCallback, this);
       ......
       as_.start();    //action server start
       ......
    };

    virtual ~LeafRobot()
    {
       ......
    };

    bool read()
    {
       //read data and save in readList
       ......
    };

    int write()
    {
       //write data from writeList
       ......
    };

    void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& e)
    {
       //Update readList and write data to Arduino
       cout << "TimerCallback\n";
       write();
       if(read())
       {
           return;
       }
       usleep(1000);
       if(read())
       {
           return;
       }
    };

    void executeCB(actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> goal_)
    {
       //Action server callback function
        cout << "executeCB\n";
        actionlib::ActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>::Goal goal = *(goal_.getGoal());
        goal_handle_ = goal_;
        addWaypoints(goal.trajectory);
        trackMove();

        goal_handle_.setAccepted();    
        result_.error_code = result_.SUCCESSFUL;
        goal_handle_.setSucceeded(result_);
    };

    void trackMove()
    {
       //Every points will load to writeList(a point). 
       //And If readList(a point) is equal writeList(a point), 
       //the function will load next point to writeList.
       ......
    };
    ......
    ......
private:
    ......
    ......
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Time time_current, time_prev;
    ros::Timer timer;
    double clock;
    actionlib::ActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>  as_;    ![image description](http://)
    control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult result_; 
    ......
    ......
};
#endif //LEAFROBOT
```

The main function just have a LeafRobot Object and other simple code.

When it run, terminal just like this.

```
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
executeCB
TrackMoving 
Arrive to 0 th point : 
Arrive to 1 th point : 
Ignore 1 th point : 
Arrive to 2 th point : 
Ignore 2 th point : 
Arrive to 3 th point : 
Ignore 3 th point : 
Arrive to 4 th point :
```

After `TrackMoving`  display , it always display `Arrive to X th point :` or `Ignore X th point :` .
It means, `timerCallback` didn't be called when `executeCB` running.
Maybe I need to use timer in C++, or don't use ROS timer and update `readList`&`writeList` in main function , through it could not very accurate.

Welcome to take some advise to me.That all, Thanks for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342115/timer-callback-function-do-not-working-when-action-server-be-called?/) by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-20**:\

> The main function just have a LeafRobot Object and other simple code.

could be, but I have a feeling the cause of what you observe is in that code.

So please show it.

**Comment by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) on 2020-01-25**:
If you want to get it in detail. Here is. [link text](https://github.com/Xueming10wu/Leaf_robot_ros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right, I don't know what happened. I just replaced actionlib::**ActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>**
as_ with actionlib::`Simple`**ActionServer<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction>**  as_, and change some code, like executeCB(const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoalConstPtr &goal). Now it looks like action tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29.

Amazing Timer callback function could be called when action-server callback function running.

Now, terminal just like this.

```
TrackMoving 
Arrive to 0 th point : 
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
Arrive to 1 th point : 
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
Arrive to 2 th point : 
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
Arrive to 3 th point : 
TimerCallback
TimerCallback
```

It's amazing! I guess ActionServer &  `Simple`ActionServer are very different. It could be interrupted or not interrupted by other callback function? So actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials just have usage about `SimpleActionServer`? Maybe,SimpleActionServer is better than ActionServer?

---

Originally posted by [snowman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37326/snowman/) with karma: 16 on 2020-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0